# Firefox openURL : OSX Command Line

Tags: macos, firefox

### Context

I want to open a Firefox browser from the command line and have it go to youtube.com

I have tried:
    open /Applications/Firefox.app --args -remote "openURL(www.youtube.com, new-tab)"

It successfully opens a Firefox, but does not navigate to youtube.com

### Question:

How do I fix this?

Answer (score 74, accepted):

`open -a Firefox 'http://www.youtube.com/'`

Comment: you don't need to capitalize `firefox`

Answer (score 16):

If firefox is your default browser you can simply use: `open 'http://www.youtube.com'`

Answer (score 8):

Maybe you can append two aliases, edit ~/.bash_profile, append code below:

```
open_by_browser(){ open -a $1 $2}
alias firefox='open_by_browser firefox'
alias chrome='open_by_browser "Google Chrome"'
```

then you can open html file by Firefox

```
firefox xxx.html
```

or by Chrome

```
chrome xxx.html
```

Answer (score 3):

The others' answers work by the way, but another way you can do it is:

```
/Applications/Firefox.app/Contents/MacOS/firefox "youtube.com"
```

Comment: Didn't work for me if Browser is already open. It says `A copy of Firefox is already open. Only one copy of Firefox can be open at a time.`

Answer (score 1):

You can open Firefox to a specific url and pass params if you want. Note: kiosk mode is an example only supported in Firefox 71 beta.

```
open -a /Applications/Firefox.app "https://stackoverflow.com" --args --kiosk
```